# i follow this example but result has "Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

i follow these example code, but the result has "Process finished with exit code 0" i dont know what is wrong. plz could you guys tell me what i need to fix that?

```
import turtle
import numpy as np
pixelSize=10
def putPixel(x,y,pSize,pCol):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x*pSize,(-1)*y*pSize)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.fillcolor(pCol)
    turtle.setheading(45)
    turtle.circle(pSize/2,steps=4)
    turtle.end_fill()

    faceImg=np.array(
        [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
         [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
    smileImg=np.array(
        [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
    for j in range(0,16):
        for i in range(0,16):
            if(faceImg[j][i]>0):
                putPixel(i,j,pixelSize,'orange')
            else:
                putPixel(i,j,pixelSize,'white')

    for j in range(0,16):
        for i in range(0,16):
            if(smileImg[j][i]>1):
                putPixel(i+20,j,pixelSize,'red')
            else:
                putPixel(i+20,j,pixelSize,'white')
```

i try to follow the text book, and 1 to 12 lines it's exactly same with text and before i follow the other example that code and have result. but now i didnt get any result or any pop window only got that resule "Process finished with exit code 0" i dont know what is wrong

Comment: Can you post the full error message received?

Comment: result only "Process finished with exit code0" and cant see anything

Comment: haha thanks, guys. it's not a problem with tabulation just indent problems. i fix it

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with tabulation. I think It should be like this:

```
 import turtle
 import numpy as np
 pixelSize=10
 def putPixel(x,y,pSize,pCol):
     turtle.penup()
     turtle.goto(x*pSize,(-1)*y*pSize)
     turtle.pendown()
     turtle.begin_fill()
     turtle.fillcolor(pCol)
     turtle.setheading(45)
     turtle.circle(pSize/2,steps=4)
     turtle.end_fill()
```

And then your main code without tabulation:

```
faceImg=np.array(
    [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
smileImg=np.array(
    [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
for j in range(0,16):
    for i in range(0,16):
        if(faceImg[j][i]>0):
            putPixel(i,j,pixelSize,'orange')
        else:
            putPixel(i,j,pixelSize,'white')

for j in range(0,16):
    for i in range(0,16):
        if(smileImg[j][i]>1):
            putPixel(i+20,j,pixelSize,'red')
        else:
            putPixel(i+20,j,pixelSize,'white')
```

This way when you run this script main code will execute. Or you can also make a min() function:

```
 def main():
     faceImg=...
```

And for running main() funtion in second case insert this code in the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```